# Cannot connect to a oracle database using intellij Datagrip

Tags: datagrip

Getting the error:

IO Error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.
Authentication lapse 0ms.

update: even though I am connecting to an Oracle 19c database when I change the driver to the one before oracle 11.2 it works i however still get a warning message however I would still like it to work with the recent driver is there anything I need to configure to get it to work.

Comment: _Help | Show Log in <...>_ probably will show more details with stacktraces that we can investigate further.